# Invalid X-Forwarded-For header with cloudflare and ingress-nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloudflare

I'm having some trouble getting the correct IP headers. I am using the following proxy setup:

Cloudflare -> Amazon NLB -> Ingress-nginx (k8s)

my ingress-nginx has the following config:

```
  config:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    real-ip-header: "CF-Connecting-IP"
    forwarded-for-header: "CF-Connecting-IP"
    set-real-ip-from: "0.0.0.0/0"
    proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
    proxy-buffers-number: "8"
```

For some reason the x-real-ip header is correct, but the x-forwarded-for header is not:

```
REMOTE ADDR: 127.0.0.1
X FORWARDED FOR: 10.0.102.38 <- Wrong
X-REAL-IP: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx <- Correct
```

The ingress-nginx loadbalancer (NLB) has:

```
External Traffic Policy:  Local
```

as per the doc. And the following annotations:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: 3600
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: *
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: xxxx
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

To be on the safe side I also enabled ExternalTrafficPolicy: Local on the app's service but to no avail.

Enabling use-proxy-protocol: "true" in the config breaks the app (probably because of CloudFlare).

```
2021-09-19 12:42:17 
" while reading PROXY protocol, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is similar issie on GitHub [Problem with HTTPS, CloudFlare and X-Forwarded-Port header #6358](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6358). The possible solution is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6358#issuecomment-721154950).

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare supports the `X-Forwarded-For` header, so you could try configuring:

```
config:
   [...]
   forwarded-for-header: "X-Forwarded-For"
```

You seem to be able of reading `CF-Connecting-IP` correctly in your setup, so `X-Forwarded-For` should also be available in the request coming from Cloudflare.

For more information you can [refer to the support article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-).

Comment: This unfortunately did not help, also tried every possible setting there.